# Layout my main.js - is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following 3 functions:

```
function A(){}
```

and

```
function B(){}
```

and finally

```
function C(){}
```

They are all in one file called main.js (main.js is the file that will contain all the main JavaScript functions for the website), and it looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   function A(){}
   function B(){}
   function C(){}
});
```

---

**Okay, and?** `functionA & B`needs to run ONLY on "window-resize and on-load" and when the screen size is above 770px and below 1024px. But function C does not require any of the above requirements to work.

Any ideas how I can layout the main.js to adapt to these changes? here is a jsFiddle with my scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/Z57Dh/

The following two functions, have to work as normal - i.e when load...
`//Prevent clicking on .active & disabled links` and `//Off-canvas menu`

But `//Show the side-by-side responsively` only needs to run when the screen width is below 770px.

However the `//Grid system` has to run when the width is above 770px and below 1024px

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function C(){}
});

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    if($(window).height() > 770 && $(window).height() < 1024 {
        function A(){}
        function B(){}
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a problem, I can't have both of them in one file, when I do - the functions inside them stops working - why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the functions ahead of time
var A = function () {console.log('a'); },
    B = function () {console.log('b'); },
    C = function () {console.log('c'); },
    AB = function() {
        var $window = $(window);

        // only run A and B if window is within boundaries
        if ($window.width() > 770 && $window.width() < 1024) {
            A();
            B();
        }
    };

// run functions when needed
$(function () {
    // run A and B on document ready
    AB();
    C();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        // run A and B when window resized
        AB();
    });;
});
```

Comment: Can you please put back the old version so I can try it?

Comment: `C();` calls function C, which is defined earlier by `function C(){};`

Comment: The functions runs when I start re-sizing. They suppose to work on resize yes but only at the specified width's

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47963/discussion-between-loai-and-mikhail)